# let me know how to pass view model data to persistence model

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, persistence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oUMv.png)

```
    public async Task<ResultModel> AddPnrListByParams(AddPnrModel model)
    {

        AddPnrModel addPnrModels = new AddPnrModel();
        {
            addPnrModels.OrgDestFrom = model.OrgDestFrom;
            addPnrModels.OrgDestTo = model.OrgDestTo;
            addPnrModels.AirLineName = model.AirLineName;
            addPnrModels.FlightNo = model.FlightNo;
            addPnrModels.DepartureDate = model.DepartureDate;
            addPnrModels.DepartureTime = model.DepartureTime;
            addPnrModels.ArrivalTime = model.ArrivalTime;
            addPnrModels.DepartureTerminal = model.DepartureTerminal;
            addPnrModels.ArrivalTerminal = model.ArrivalTerminal;
            addPnrModels.FareBasis = model.FareBasis;
            addPnrModels.FareDet = model.FareDet;
            addPnrModels.BagInfo = model.BagInfo;
            addPnrModels.ClassType = model.ClassType;
            addPnrModels.NextDayArrival = model.NextDayArrival;
            addPnrModels.FareRule = model.FareRule;
        }
        _db.FlightSearchResults.Add(addPnrModels);       
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return null;

    }
```

I want to pass my ADDPNRMODEL to FLIGHTSEARCHMODEL and FLIGHTSEARCHMODEL is created I persistence folder I don't know how to solve this issue basically I want to create Post API to submit data in database

Comment: You can only add  `FilghtSearchResult` type to db with  `_db.FlightSearchResults.Add(xx);`.You can try to convert `addPnrModels` to `FilghtSearchResult`  type.Can you share the structure of `FilghtSearchResult`?

Comment: @YiyiYou i can share but the problem is in my FlightSearchResult Model there are more than 100 properties

Comment: If so,you need to convert `addPnrModels` to `FilghtSearchResult` type and then add it to db.